# How to keep margin top constant when Div's height changes

Tags: html, css

I have this strange issue, I am building a simple html and css and js popup login interface, I don't know why any time I change from Login popup to Signup/Register popup the margin top changes.

I want to keep the margin-top constant when I change from Login popup to Register popup, especially on mobile view, I need it to be constant, to not distort the mobile view.

Kindly look at the image below and code below.

Firstly, **Login Interface**, kindly note the margin top above it

[image: Login Interface, kindly note the margin top above it]

Now When I click Register it opens the register popup as required but alters the margin-top set.

Secondly, **Register interface**, but margin top has changed, I don't want it to change.

[image: Register interface, but margin top has changed]

My code

```html
    <div id ="open_login_interface">
    <div class="open_login_interface_inner">
    <div class="log-reg-container">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-head">
    <!--Bla Bla Bla-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="box" id="login-pop">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="box" id="sign-pop">
    
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <!--Bla Bla Bla-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
    #open_login_interface {
    display: block;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(ie.png);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(11,11,11,0.1), rgba(11,11,11,0.6)) repeat-x rgba(11,11,11,0.2);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(11,11,11,0.1)), to(rgba(11,11,11,0.6))) repeat-x rgba(11,11,11,0.2);
    z-index: 8888;
    }

    .open_login_interface_inner {
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 15%;
    width: 28%;
    min-height: 20%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 75%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    top: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 640px){
    .open_login_interface_inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: calc((100vh - 100vw)/2);
    }
    }
    
    .log-reg-container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }   
 
    .modal-content {      
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    }
   
     .modal-body {
     width:100%;
     }

    .box {
     padding-left: 0px;
     padding-right: 0px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the dominant property of the CSS is centering your modal. So bigger modal, less margin.
Just make center it horizontally (and not vertically) by transform: translate(-50%, 0);

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you gave us, but we can't even run/debug it right because its missing code. Can you update your code?

```css
#open_login_interface {
display: block;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: url(ie.png);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(11,11,11,0.1), rgba(11,11,11,0.6)) repeat-x rgba(11,11,11,0.2);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(11,11,11,0.1)), to(rgba(11,11,11,0.6))) repeat-x rgba(11,11,11,0.2);
z-index: 8888;
}

.open_login_interface_inner {
background: #fff;
position: fixed;
margin: 0 auto;
margin: 0;
margin-top: 15%;
width: 28%;
min-height: 20%;
height: auto;
max-height: 75%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
top: 10%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
border: 0px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

@media (max-width: 640px){
.open_login_interface_inner {
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
margin-top: calc((100vh - 100vw)/2);
}
}

.modal-content {      
height:auto;
width:100%;
}

 .modal-body {
 width:100%;
 }

.box {
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div id ="open_login_interface">
<div class="open_login_interface_inner">
<div class="log-reg-container">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-head">
<!--Bla Bla Bla-->
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="box" id="login-pop">

</div>

<div class="box" id="sign-pop">

</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<!--Bla Bla Bla-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```